# Send commands from a web page to winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, httplistener, httplistenerrequest

I've done an application in C#, using winform, that now is required to be controlled remotely (only some functions) from a webpage self-hosted on a lighthttp server (included as a class in my application solution).

This is the server code (thx to David's BlogEngine):

```
public class WebServer
{
    private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
    private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

    public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
    {
        if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            throw new NotSupportedException(
                "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

        // URI prefixes are required, for example 
        // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // A responder method is required
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("method");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

        _responderMethod = method;
        _listener.Start();
    }

    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
        : this(prefixes, method) { }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
            try
            {
                while (_listener.IsListening)
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                    {
                        var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                        try
                        {
                            string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                            byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                            ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                        }
                        catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                        finally
                        {
                            // always close the stream
                            ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                        }
                    }, _listener.GetContext());
                }
            }
            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _listener.Close();
    }
}
```

and this is the code, inside my winform application, used to turn it on:

```
    WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost:8080/test/");
    ws.Run();
```

This is the html returned to the server:

```
public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

When I open "localhost:8080/test" on my browser it works like a charm, but..
I don't know how to pass info from the webpage to the application to fire an event on it.

i.e. If I press a button "close" on the webpage it fires the closing event on the winform application.

What I need to implement to achieve this objective?

(I will update this post step by step with my future progress to keep it useful to everybody)

Comment: Do you know anything already about how web applications work?

Comment: @Evk only in theory, never done it in pratic.

Comment: Well you create html page which you return on default request (in your SendResponse). That html page contains a button, when you click it you make another request. For this request, instead of returning html in SendResponse - you close your form. So basically you analyze HttpListenerRequest and make different actions based on that...

Comment: I am having a hard time thinking of a scenario where this would actually be required. What is your application and why do you want a web page to control it's UI elements? If I were doing something like this I would be creating common assemblies used by the winforms application and the web application.

Comment: @RossMiller The winform application is used to speak, via sockets, with another external application, sending and receiving messages.
I need a web UI to control the main functions of my application (like send this kind of message or analyze that other, etc..) so I can interact with it by a remote workstation. 
It must be hosted on this self-hosting lighthttp webserver because the machines we use to execute my application are without IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Grapevine](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine) - this is the exact niche it was built for.

It allows you to embed a simple REST server in your winform application and easily map incoming requests to methods. From their, your webapp can interact with it by sending simple requests (either via JavaScript on the front end or more C# on the backend.)

https://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/en/getting-started.html

Comment: interesting! did not know this was implemented. Kudos to the developer(s)